# Mysql stored procedure does not produce expected result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a `mysql stored procedure` to fetch value from one table to another table. When I call the stored procedure it runs fine but problem is, it is `inserting previous column` value if the `current column` value is `null`.

Example : suppose second employee name column is null, since it is running in loop it is inserting first employee name in the place of second employee name but i want column value in my `new table` to be null if column value in my `existing table` is null.Below is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `frstprocedure`()
BEGIN
DECLARE emp_name varchar(225);
DECLARE emp_age varchar(225);
DECLARE emp_dept varchar(225);

DECLARE masterCursor CURSOR for select empname,empage,empdept from Employee;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
SET done=0;
OPEN masterCursor;
my_loop: LOOP
FETCH masterCursor into emp_name,emp_age, emp_dept;
IF done THEN
CLOSE masterCursor;
LEAVE my_loop;
END IF;
insert into second_table values(emp_name,emp_age, emp_dept);
END LOOP my_loop;
END
```

Comment: The name of the loop is `my_loop`, but you have `LEAVE ticket_loop`. Is that a typo in the question or in the real procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding following line `after insert statement` in your stored procedure,

```
SET emp_name=null;
SET emp_age=null;
SET emp_dept-null
```

this will initialize all the field values to null in every iteration, so correct values will be stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `default values` while declaring your variables.see the code below

```
DECLARE emp_name varchar(225) default null;
DECLARE emp_age varchar(225) default null;
DECLARE emp_dept varchar(225) default null;
```